# How to test window.print function of JavaScript when printer is not available?

Tags: javascript, css, printing

Well, i am using JavaScript window.print() method and has no printer attached so can i get the output as an image or pdf to be sure that i am getting the desired output??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try installing a print-to-pdf program like this one [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. You cannot test if a printer is available or not on the client machine unless you use some browser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In most new browsers, you have a print preview function that you can use to see if you get desired output based on your media:print setup in the css. `window.print` in Javascript is just to trigger the print function in the browser, and really have nothing to do with how the print looks.